# В чем ошибка кода? выдает нули

Tags: python, условия

#Рассматривается множество целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку
[1234567; 7654321], которые кратны разнице двух чисел, полученных из двух старших и двух
младших разрядов. Например, для числа 2435467 два числа будут 24 и 67. Соответствующая
разница – 43. В ответе запишите два целых числа: сначала количество таких чисел, затем –
максимальное из них.

```
max_=0
count=0
for i in range(1245673, 7654322):
    b=i//100000
    c=i%100
if b>c:
    a=b-c
if b<c:
    a=c-b
if i%a==0:
    count+=1
    max_=i
print(count,max_)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Перенеси все проверки внутрь цикла, сейчас у тебя проверяется только последнее число. И почитай что-нибудь об элементарных способах отладки.

Comment: а, точно, спасибо